# Prevent scrolling animation from triggering when navigating back in history

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following code to automatically scroll a page a bit on first load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("body,html").delay(1000).animate({scrollTop: 300}, 1000);

});
```

However, if the user scrolls the page manually and clicks on a link, I would like him to be able to go back to that link if he navigates back in history. Currently, if the user goes back, the animation will trigger again and the page will be scrolled to the top+300 instead, interrupting the workflow.

Comment: You can add a condition that checks if `scrollTop` is zero and only then trigger the automatic scroll.

Comment: You can maintain the user's scrolltop position in the local storage of the last page visit before navigation so when you get back just read it and put the user there.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj, that sounds easiest, please post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a condition that checks if scrollTop is zero and only then trigger the automatic scroll:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if( $(window).scrollTop() === 0 ){
    $("body,html").delay(1000).animate({scrollTop: 300}, 1000);
  }//if
});// document ready
```

Or better still:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout( checkAndScroll, 1000 );
});// document ready

function checkAndScroll(){
  if( $(window).scrollTop() === 0 ){
     $("body,html").animate({scrollTop: 300}, 1000);
  }
}//checkAndScroll()
```

This second approach will also take care of the case, when user initiates scroll before 1 second.